# How can I find the value of a specific property from all instances of an object?

Tags: javascript

In case this gets labeled as a duplicate or something similar; I just wanted to put it out there that I looked for an answer for about 3-4 days. The articles, topics and related questions that showed up did not solve my problem. If they do happen to be the solution, I currently don't and didn't understand why.

How can I, for example, loop through all instances of the player object and return each instance's value for the id property?

```
function player(id, damage, arena)
{
this.id = id;
this.damage = damage;
this.arena = arena;
}

var player1 = new player(101,10, true);
var player2 = new player(102,5, true);
var player3 = new player(103,20, true);
```

Don't laugh at me!
Even though I'm like 65% percent sure a string wouldn't serve as a reference
to an object, all my train of thoughts tend to revert back to something that works like this..

```
var txt = "";
for (i=1; i <= player_count; i++)

{
var x = "player"+i;
txt += " " + x.id;
}

document.GetElementById("someTextDivOrSomething").innerHTML = txt;
```

Can someone explain how I can go about doing this, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: *I'm like 65% percent sure a string wouldn't serve as a reference to an object* yet with 35% confidence I say: `txt += window["player" + i].id`. Of course you'd need to know `player_count` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You need some [structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to hold the [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), i.e. the representation of your players as you create them.

later on you can loop over the [elements of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) your players collection

e.g.

```
let players = {};

...

players[101] = new player(101,10, true);
players[102] = new player(102,15, true);
players[103] = new player(103,20, true);

...

let txt = ""
for (let p of players) {
    txt += " " + p.id
    // note we need a name which is not "player" as that is taken
}
```

Comment: I don't quiet understand though. *editing*(hit enter by mistake)
in the for loop what is going inside of it that references/returns the id?

Comment: Each time the loop goes round p is a different player

Comment: So it outputs all the info for each player instance? then i can sort through the text to find a specific value with some other coding?

Comment: edited to add an example of "something involving player"; for (let p of players) {} itself does nothing, you put inside the {} things you want to do with each player

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure for the object constructor. The private variable `players` contains all instances of the class `Player`.

```js
var Player = function () {
        var players = [];
        return function(id, damage, arena) {
            this.id = id;
            this.damage = damage;
            this.arena = arena;
            this.players = players;
            this.players.push(this);
        };
    }();

var player1 = new Player(101, 10, true);
var player2 = new Player(102, 5, true);
var player3 = new Player(103, 20, true);
document.write(player1.players.length + '<br>'); // 3
document.write(player2.players.length + '<br>'); // 3
player3.players.forEach(function (a) { document.write('id: ' + a.id + '<br>'); });  // 101, 102, 103
```